# What am I doing wrong with inserting?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried both

```
$query = "INSERT INTO reservation VALUES ('".$hour."','".$minute."','".$day."','".$month."','".$year."','".$name."','".$table."')";

$query = "INSERT INTO reservation VALUES ('$hour','$minute','$day','$month','$year','$name','$table')";
```

But none of them work, I get a blank page, and no errors in my error logs. I tried doing echo to all the variables and I got their values.

Here is the overall function:

```
function makeReservation($trtime,$hour,$minute,$day,$month,$year,$name,$table,&$db)
{
//$query = "INSERT INTO reservation VALUES ('".$hour."','".$minute."','".$day."','".$month."','".$year."','".$name."','".$table."')";
$query = "INSERT INTO reservation VALUES ('$hour','$minute','$day','$month','$year','$name','$table')";
$result = $db->query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Are you escaping these variables before putting them into the query? Do any of the values contain single quotes? Is this the exact number of columns this table has, and the right order? Have you tried printing out `$query` and running it against the database directly?

Comment: There is a DATETIME type in MySQL which could really simplify your query. On topic, if it doesn't return any error, than at least make sure you're working on the good database.

Comment: Why do you have hour, minute, day, month and year columns instead of a single `DATETIME` type column?

Comment: All values are int except for $name which is text. I'm working on the right database because SELECT and DELETE functions are working fine,

Comment: That doesn't answer any of the questions, but it does lead to the advice that you shouldn't have single quotes around numeric values.

Comment: Add your columns to the query, probably there's a mismatch try "INSERT INTO reservation (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7) VALUES ('$hour','$minute','$day','$month','$year','$name','$table')";

Comment: what does mysql_error() returns?

Comment: Ahh newbie mistake.. I had the primary key set to auto-increment, so I thought I didn't need to put it. After checking how phpmyadmin did it I found out I need to set it but put NULL. THank you for all the help guys! Sorry for the disturbance!

Comment: If you don't add the primary key is not a problem, should work without it (because it is auto_increment), but it's a good practice to add NULL for pk that has auto_increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll make a few suggestions. First, I'll assume that you actually know what you're doing when you say there is no error.

1) Make sure you work on the good database. You can do a `SHOW TABLES` query to see what tables it contains, or a `SELECT * FROM reservation` to see its content.
2) Right after you insert the row, do a `SELECT * FROM reservation` query and check if your row is there.
3) Make sure you call your function...

Then, as I said in comments, you should use the DATETIME type instead of using different columns for hours, minutes, etc. If you need to select a particular attribute, use the appropriate function (for example, `SELECT HOUR(your_column)`)
The quotes around integers shouldn't make your query fails, but it's still better for clean code purposes to remove them if not necessary (and make sure you escape your data correctly, of course).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful tips! I'm still new to php/mysql so I don't know my way around a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

The php you posted looks fine.

If you're getting a blank page, it's likely that something is failing before the function calls. Maybe a parsing error?

If you're not seeing anything in the error logs, try changing your error logging settings in the php.ini.

`display_errors = E_ALL`

If you're on shared hosting, you can often override using .htaccess http://davidwalsh.name/php-values-htaccess

Comment: if you updated php.ini, it may need to restart your web server. Out of curiosity, what happens if you `error_log(mysql_error())`

Comment: What happens if you `echo $query;` and attempt to run it directly on the DB?